# How can I export the result of Pivot_Wider into Excel or CSV

Tags: r, pivot, export

I tried to Pivot_wider my two-column dataframe at it worked well, but the observations are **listed C** as shown in the **result** [image: result]

What I want to do is to export this into Excel or CSV like my **desired output** [image: OUTPUT]

Could you please guide me how Can I achieve this output in R?

Comment: Without access to your source data, no we can't.  Once you've got your data in your desired format (using `pivot_wider` or any other method), then you can export your data frame to Excel or CSV just as you would any other data frame.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post image on the site for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), but use a [representative example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead. Anyway, it's not much about the data, `write.csv` will do the job. Check ?write.csv for the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

**Your dataframe:**

```
df <- data.frame(
            Name = c("Cat", "Dog", "Cow", "Wolf", "Lion"),
            Weight = c(5,7,1000,55,400)
)
```

**to CSV:**

```
write.csv(df,"your_directory\\df.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

**to Excel:**

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(df,"your_directory\\df.xlsx")
```

Comment: Check the screenshot, it is not the same data structure, they have a list column.

Comment: @zx8754 is it? Hmmm